# Exception starting filter struts2 Unable to load configuration. What's wrong?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, struts2-spring-plugin

I'm writing a (Struts2, Spring3, Hibernate4) website for studying, but when I run this project today, these errors appeared.

Project code is [here](https://github.com/IamWilliamWang/StudentTestSystem).

```
Severe: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
... 15 more
Caused by: Cannot locate the chosen ObjectFactory implementation: spring - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider.alias(AbstractBeanSelectionProvider.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider.alias(AbstractBeanSelectionProvider.java:45)
at org.apache.struts2.config.DefaultBeanSelectionProvider.register(DefaultBeanSelectionProvider.java:356)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
... 18 more
```

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: Cannot locate the chosen ObjectFactory implementation: spring - [unknown location]

This implementation is available in [struts2-spring-plugin-x.x.x.jar](https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html). Since you are not using Maven you have to [download](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts25101), install, and add dependency to your project classpath.

Comment: how to add dependency to my project classpath

Comment: How to add dependency read [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962).